# Cannot read property 'cloneNode' of null, but works when the script is on HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting a cloneNode error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloneNode' of null at application.js:42`when I move my script into a javascript file. But the application works when the script is in the HTML page.

```
const candidatesTable = document.getElementById("candidates_example");
const newCandidatesTable = candidatesTable.cloneNode(true);

document.body.appendChild(newCandidatesTable);
```

I cannot figure out why this is happening and I am using Chrome for the browser.
https://jsfiddle.net/sithanga/sd5qtcj3/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using document.body but your script is inserted in header, before executing any code on elements you should make sure they are existing on the page. Why it works when you insert it as script tag is you are inserting it at bottom.

e.g [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event will be fired when all DOM content is loaded and ready to be interacted by your JS code.